# Footnotes in Markdown: both on Jupyter and Google Colab

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a Jupyter Notebook-based document that can work both on Binder and Google Colaboratory.

I like the *footnote idiom*, which is a Markdown/HTML hack and correctly works on Jupyter, described in

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1287#issuecomment-451080550

But it does not work on Google Colaboratory because they do not allow HTML tags in Markdown:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb#scrollTo=w86a4I4fmkvD

Is there any footnote hack working both on Jupyter Notebook and Google Colaboratory?

Edit: the idiom also does not work within VS Code Jupyter extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Google Colab accepts anchor HTML tags `<a name="..."></a>`. The following Markdown snippet works both with Jupyter Notebook (Binder) and Google Colab.

```
Example of footnote.<a name="cite_ref-1"></a>[<sup>[1]</sup>](#cite_note-1)
Example of footnote.<a name="cite_ref-2"></a>[<sup>[2]</sup>](#cite_note-2)


<a name="cite_note-1"></a>1. [^](#cite_ref-1) footnote 1
<a name="cite_note-2"></a>2. [^](#cite_ref-2) footnote 2
```

An example notebook is [here](https://gist.github.com/tueda/c2a56ea8e0ba72890a2b886a162e4e2d).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with VSCode or Jupyter Notebook Preview on GitHub.

| Software | Does it work? | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jupyter Notebook | Yes | 6.3.0 |
| Google Colaboratory | Yes | Feb 25, 2022 |
| Visual Studio Code | No | 1.65.1 |
| Jupyter Notebook Preview on GitHub | No | as of 9 March 2022 |

Comment: Though the original problem (Binder and Colab) was solved, I hope there would be a more "universal" solution working with VSCode and GitHub Preview...

Comment: I think it does work on VSCode now (at least for me)

Comment: Well, to me, it doesn't work with VSCode 1.75.1...

Comment: Ah nvm sorry, it does get clickable and blue but does not actually link label and ref.